# service created but not started

Tags: windows-services, device-driver

I am trying to run a driver I created as a service. I managed to create a service out of the driver (using "*sc.exe create ...*"): The service now appears in the registry (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/services/mydriver). However the service cannot be started! When I use net start [myservice], I get the following output:

*error 1275: This driver has been blocked from loading*

One thing looked suspicious to me: The entry in the registry for my driver: The value of "**ImagePath**" was "\??[correct path]". I manually removed the "\??\" so that the correct path was left. However it did not solve the problem, instead I got an other error message (Error 123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect).

By searching on the internet, I found out that this error 1275 indicates that a key in the registry is missing or corrupted. This makes sense as I modified it manually, so the value of "**ImagePath**" is probably corrupted. However I don't see anything wrong with the value I entered:

"C:\ledrivertest\driver1\bin\hello.sys"

Is there some kind of special syntax for the path of a driver binary which I don't know about?

I use Windows 7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: One thing I forgot to add: "sc query state= all | find [myservice]" won't return the service I am trying to start.

Comment: \??\ is fine, why remove that?

Comment: Is it? I thought it was a sign indicating that the path was wrong. You think something else caused the error?

Comment: absolutely something else caused the problem

Comment: is the driver signed? I also admit to having no idea about running drivers as services.

Comment: You're right, \??\ seems to be fine: When I remove them, the error is not the same, it becomes: Error 123: The Filename, Directory Name, or Volume Label Syntax Is Incorrect. (I was wrong when I said it did not change the error, I will edit my question). So any idea about what could cause the 1275 error? Maybe I just messed up my registry by modifying it manually, any idea how to investigate this?

Comment: is the driver signed? That error means the driver has been blocked from loading, lack of signing is most common cause I think.

Comment: Sorry I had not seen your question when I wrote my last comment. No the driver is not signed,  or at least I guess it isn't, since I made it myself from a tutorial (it is just a helloworld test).

Comment: If you are on 64 bit windows then it needs to be signed. Although I think devs can set a switch to bypass that requirement.

Comment: That's right I am on 64-bit windows! Thank you very much for your answer, I didn't know anything about that sign-stuff. I will try to investigate it to solve my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running on a 64 bit system, and you haven't signed the driver, the most likely explanation for error 1275 is that Windows blocked the driver due to it being unsigned.